# Problem with expansion tag

Tags: discussion, support

I was looking at the [battlestar-galactica](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica) tag and noticed that it seems to define two additional tags for the expansions, namely "battlestar-galactica-pegasus" and "battlestar-galactica-exodus".  Neither tag has any entries.  However, there are two questions   tagged [exodus](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exodus). I attempted to edit those questions so that their tag was "battlestar-galactica-exodus", but encountered an error:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> 'battlestar-galactica-exodus' exceeds maximum tag length of 25 characters

What should we do about this?  Maybe switch to "bsg-exodus"?  But that seems less clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad - I think I added those to the wiki blindly believing I'd used them before, but clearly I hadn't.  I think `bsg-exodus` is clear enough personally but I'm intimately familiar with BSG already so I'm biased.

Edit: I fixed the wiki (edit queued, that is) to link to the existing `pegasus` and `exodus` tags, at least.  They may be fine as they are.

Comment: I recommend renaming the tags to add the "bsg-" prefix.  Even if people don't know "bsg", the scoping will help to convey that these aren't new (as-yet-unknown-to-the-reader) games.

Answer (score 3):

### We can now rename it

[All sites are now allowed to use tags with 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/191265). Thus we can rename these tags to [battlestar-galactica-pegasus](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica-pegasus) and [battlestar-galactica-exodus](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica-exodus).